# Aligning baseline of textView inside HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, horizontalscrollview, baseline

I have two `textView`. I want their `baseLine` to be aligned. It would have been trivial task, but one `textView` is inside `HorizontalScrollView`, which makes it difficult. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: the screenshot would be great